# How do you find out where a certain key value pair was put inside the Owin context in Microsoft Katana?

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-identity, owin, katana

I'd like to find out which piece of code put what value for the key "security.Authenticate" in the `Owin` context.

How do I do that?

I am using Microsoft Katana with AspNet Identity.

**Background**

I've read the OAuth 2.0 specification but my goal is to find out how Microsoft implements it in their code.

So, when you open an ASP.NET MVC project template with **Individual Accounts** authentication in Visual Studio 2015, you get a lot of boiler plate code.

Over the years, I have learn to understand most of it, but every now and then, I'll forget and start chasing things down using Reflector and IL Spy.

Right now, I am trying to understand how the `ChallengeResult` class that comes in with the boilerplate redirects to the OAuth provider when it doesn't at all seem apparent looking at its `ExecuteResult` method that it does.

My research led me to a line of code that gets a `func` from the `OwinContext` and executes it. The key that the `func` was stored with in the `OwinContext` was "security.Authenticate."

```
// Microsoft.Owin.Security.AuthenticationManager
internal Func<string[], 
        Action<IIdentity, 
        IDictionary<string, string>, 
        IDictionary<string, object>,  object>,
        object, 
        Task> AuthenticateDelegate
{
    get
    {
        return this._context
        .Get<Func<string[], 
        Action<IIdentity, IDictionary<string, string>, IDictionary<string, object>, object>, 
        object, Task>>("security.Authenticate");
    }
}
```

Comment: Good question and I did not find that quickly as well. Can I ask what lead you to investigate this particular item?

Comment: @trailmax Just curiosity. I like to tear abstractions apart and look inside. I usually always write my own OAuth code because it is much simple that way. But on projects in the past, I have used Microsoft's code and every time, I will chase it down to the point where I know what's going on. Thing is: the next time, I will have forgotten most of the bits. I am doing it again because I want to integrate with Facebook. Integrating is not the challenge. In fact, it's a piece of cake. Just that I hate black boxes unless I know what's going on inside.

Comment: That's a great aspiration! Let me see if I can find it...

Comment: Look here: https://github.com/jchannon/katanaproject/blob/master/src/Microsoft.Owin.Security/Infrastructure/OwinRequestExtensions.cs#L21

Comment: And this is the value of the constant: https://github.com/jchannon/katanaproject/blob/master/src/Microsoft.Owin.Security/Infrastructure/Constants.cs#L7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This value is set in [OwinRequestExtensions](https://github.com/jchannon/katanaproject/blob/master/src/Microsoft.Owin.Security.Cookies/CookieAuthenticationMiddleware.cs) that is used in [AuthenticationHandler](https://github.com/jchannon/katanaproject/blob/master/src/Microsoft.Owin.Security.Cookies/CookieAuthenticationMiddleware.cs). And after the long chain of calls, it ends up in [CookieAuthenticationMiddleware](https://github.com/jchannon/katanaproject/blob/master/src/Microsoft.Owin.Security.Cookies/CookieAuthenticationMiddleware.cs) and other authentication middlewares.

Comment: Thanks so much. I was close. I did `var func = context.HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Get<Func<string[], Action<IIdentity, IDictionary<string, string>, IDictionary<string, object>, object>, object, Task>>("security.Authenticate");
                Debug.Print(func.GetType().ToString());
                Debug.Print(func.Target.ToString());` inside the `ChallengeResult.Execute`.

Comment: I have a related question about `scopes` in OAuth but I guess I'll make a new question about it. The summary of this question is: I notice that the new boilerplate code that comes with VS 2015 and Facebook authentication does not get the user's email address. Gets only user's full name. Also it does not ask the user for the confirmation dialog "This app wants to know this, that and the other about you. Agree?" Where can I force Katana to add scopes to get the user's email address and also present the login confirmation dialog on Facebook?

Comment: yes, the issue was that this value was defined in more than one constant. And you had to trace usage of both constants.

Comment: Regarding Facebook - no idea. I actually did not work with Facebook auth, so better have it as a separate question

Comment: How did you find it? Teach me to find it please?

Comment: I had both codebases of Katana and Identity in my drive. I've done grep-search (grepWin is great for this if you are on Windows) for this value. It showed me couple constants defined in Katana codebase. Then used Resharper to trace usage of both constants and bingo!

Comment: Awesome. Thank you. :-)